# How to keep GPS / location service on android always on?

Tags: android, gps, google-play

How to keep GPS / location service on android always on?

If there is code to implement this or any available app on playstore ?

I need to track my employees when they are in delivery routes.

Comment: See https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/155287/how-do-i-prevent-my-gps-tracking-app-from-stopping/155293#155293